Send Maill of BCC displayed "undisclosed-recipients"
When I use org.springframework.mail.javamail send "toBcc()" to a large number of recipients, the recipient of the message is always displayed as "undisclosed-recipients".
I want the location of the email recipient to show a code that I customize. I've been searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

The B in BCC means Blind.

Is it sufficient to set the "To" value to a dummy address? "Undisclosed Recipients" was always an alternative to a dummy address when every recipient of importance was BCCed.
